# my github desktop doesn't work

Tags: github, github-for-windows

When I hit 'sync', it just display 'syncing' and nothing is going on.(i mean process bar on top didn't move) and when I try to see my repo's history, it shows me change tab's page. also, when I try tutorial, there is one message box wit 'got it!' and 'Learn more'.

Uninstall and install again my Github desktop, delete/make repo and reboot several but they didn't help.

[Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pFai6QZygQk&feature=youtu.be) is the link of the video of my problem

Is my Github desktop broken? or is there solution?

Comment: here is [video](https://youtu.be/pFai6QZygQk) for this problem

Comment: I checked the video. How long did you wait? Sometimes if your github project have alot of stuff, it takes quite some time for it to move it, specially if you have poor internet connection. Also, did you press the sync button at the upstream branch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it this way:

1. Uninstall GitHub Desktop
2. Reboot
3. Delete AppData\Local\GitHub
4. Install GitHub Desktop with ownership

I don't know what was problem.

Comment: Maybe the problem was that github did not have permission to download files into your computer in order to sync it.

Comment: I don't know how to give it permission. should I use other GUI git tool?

Comment: If your Github-desk is now working, there is no need to.